# Process a file line by line

Tags: java, io

I am working on homework but currently stuck.

I need to process a file and return number of characters, words, and lines.

I am particularly lost on how I can process the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to loop while `Scanner#hasNextLine` returns `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(file);
    //rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(your_file));` and scan the file using `while(scan.hasNext())`. place your counter inside the loop and count the `lines`,`words` and `characters`.

Comment: Teacher requires us to have a separate method to process and two more to count which is why I'm stuck

Comment: Actually I think I see what you mean now...
but I am still very confused. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: what are you confused about? how does your code look like now? are there any errors?